# Prevent ffmpeg drop when dropped input icecast stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I transcode an ICECAST stream and out it to udp multicast via ffmpeg with the following command:

> ffmpeg -i http://ip:8000/icecast -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ar
>   44100 -ac 2 -ab 128 -f mpegts udp://ip:port

But if an icecast stream will be drop then ffmpeg drop also. **Is the way keep ffmpeg running?** 
The best variant will be play silent in *udp://ip:port* stream when icecast stream droped and continue playing when this stream will be available again. 
I routed output from wget and [fIcy](https://github.com/wavexx/fIcy) to ffmpeg, but no luck. **Is exist any software solution for it?**

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but worth a try

Shorter method

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -i http://ip:8000/icecast
       -vn -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128 -f mpegts udp://ip:port
```

Longer method (try if above doesn't work)

```
ffmpeg -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -i http://ip:8000/icecast
       -f lavfi -i anullsrc
       -filter_complex "[0]aresample=async=1[main];
                        [main][1]amix=dropout_transition=0,volume=2"
       -vn -c:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128 -f mpegts udp://ip:port
```

Comment: Thank you! Very useful!
Short method: reconnecting for about 4 seconds when the input stream is drop then ffmpeg drop also. I added -reconnect_delay_max 3600 parameter also, but it's not helped.
Long method: As in the first method, reconnecting 4 seconds then writing silence, but not playing ICECAST stream when this stream running again.